# What does "%d ->" in printf mean?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I was skimming through [this](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-construct-binary-search-tree/) but in line 114 it is written `printf("%d -> ", t->value);`
what I ask is, what does `"%d ->` mean? Is it a typo or something else?

Example:

```
struct btnode {
    int value;
    struct btnode * l;
    struct btnode * r;
} * root = NULL, * temp = NULL, * t2, * t1;

void inorder(struct btnode * t) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        printf("No elements in a tree to display");
        return;
    }
    if (t->l != NULL)
        inorder(t->l);
    printf("%d -> ", t->value);
    if (t->r != NULL)
        inorder(t->r);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think its a typo? Maybe we can clarify that instead. Usually anything in a string that is preceded by '\' or '%' is printed as is.

Comment: @ChromoZoneX I think you mean things preceded by "\" and "%" will *Not* be printed as is.

Comment: ^My apologies, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing special, just a normal format string.

```
printf("%d -> ", 42);
```

outputs:

```
42 ->
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that this piece of code will print the value of `t->value` in decimal followed by the characters `->`. Nothing special, just an ordinary `printf`

Answer (score 3):

The `%d` indicates to print a int as described later in the method(`t->value`). The `->` portion is simply printing `->`.

Answer (score 3):

It simply prints a number (%d) followed by an ASCII arrow ->. There's no error.

Answer (score 3):

It is of no special meaning

Since you are using the binary tree concept, to illustrate that the elements are  **Bind** together with the link

```
Suppose you have a binary tree already constructed like this one:
               15
              /  \
             10  30
            / \    \
           5  13    35
```

if you traverse the tree in IN-ORDER then the below printf would print like this:

```
printf("%d -> ", t->value); 

5 -> 10 -> 13 -> 15 -> 30 -> 35
```